# Can Goodstein's theorem be false in some model of Peano arithmetic? How?

Tags: set-theory, arithmetic, model-theory, peano-axioms

I read that Goodstein's theorem is not provable in Peano arithmetic, but is provable in ZFC.

Now, **using Godel's completeness theorem**, we can say that, since Goodstein's theorem is not provable in Peano arithmetic, there exists a model of Peano arithmetic where the Goodstein theorem is true, and a model where the Goodstein theorem is false. ZFC is an example of the former model. **Is there an example of the latter model?**

What I am extremely confused about is that Goodstein's theorem seems to be about an **objective** statement about arithmetic : You either always reach zero using the steps, or there exists a counter-example. If the theorem has been proven to be true, **how can we ever find a model where it's false (without us re-defining the meaning of arithmetic operations)**?

If this theorem is false in a non-standard model, can that model produce a counter-example number for which this theorem is false?  **I want to understand how a *seemingly* absolute statement's truth can actually be relative to the model.**

Comment: ZFC is not a model in PA. A model of PA in which the theorem is false cannot be a model in ZFC (to be honest , I have difficulties to understand this, but I am sure someone here can completely clarify it). I am unfortunately not very firm with mathematical logic.

Comment: "the theorem has been proven to be true" in the *standard* model. According to GIT (incompleteness) and other results, there are non-standard ones.

Comment: Goodstein Th is not provable in (first-order) Peano arithmetic; thus, it is **not** a logical consequence of the axiom (by completeness of FOL). Thus, it is **not** true in every model.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I get that. I'm just looking for an example non-standard model where it isn't true and how it isn't true there. I want to get an idea of how a *seemingly* objective statement's truth can actually be relative to the model. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If this theorem isn't true in a non standard model, can that model produce a counter-example of this theorem? I mean... an actual number for which this theorem doesn't hold in that model?

Comment: An "actual number" which is a counterexample (in the model in with Goodstein is false) will (i think) be a non-standard (i.e. infinite) element in the model. So, for example, it's likely NOT something you can plug into a compueter program to see what happens.

Comment: Can Goodstein's Theorem be expressed by a first-order sentence in the language of Peano arithmetic?

Comment: @Ned Is the theorem true for finite numbers regardless of the model?

Comment: @RyderRude I don't know -- my guess is yes, but I'm not certain.

Comment: "Re-defining the meaning of arithmetic operations" is *exactly* what a model is.  A model is just any set equipped with some operations that satisfy the axioms; those operations don't have to be the usual arithmetic operations (and the set does not have to be the usual natural numbers).

Comment: @RobertShore Yes - you basically say "For every starting number $n$ there is a code for a finite sequence beginning with $n$, ending with $0$, and following the Goodstein rule."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's helpful to consider $(i)$ a simpler statement than Goodstein's theorem and $(ii)$ a weaker theory than $\mathsf{PA}$. The reason for the former is that Goodstein's theorem has lots of complexity which isn't really germane to the general logical issues at play; the reason for the latter is that there is a particular technical result ([Tennenbaum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem)) which prevents us from having *any* too-nicely-describable nonstandard models of $\mathsf{PA}$ at all, and again that makes the logical issues look more troubling than they really are.

So let's take as our statement "Every number is either even or odd" which we can formally express as $$(\star):\quad\forall x\exists y(y+y=x\vee y+y+1=x),$$ and let's take as our theory [Robinson's arithmetic $\mathsf{Q}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic). This theory, in contrast with $\mathsf{PA}$, has lots of easily-describable nonstandard models. In particular, my favorite nonstandard model of $\mathsf{Q}$ is the set $\mathfrak{P}$ of polynomials in a single variable $x$ with integer coefficients and nonnegative leading coefficient, ordered by eventual domination as $x\rightarrow\infty$. (More snappily, take the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, order it so that $p>q$ whenever $p$ is a polynomial of higher degree than $q$, and look at the nonnegative elements of that ordered ring.)

Now it's easy to show that $\mathfrak{P}$ does **not** satisfy $(\star)$: just consider the polynomial $x$ by itself. To us, this is not a natural number, but "within $\mathfrak{P}$" it looks perfectly fine. Perhaps belaboring the point, there is a unique way embedding of $\mathbb{N}$ inside $\mathfrak{P}$, and $x$ is not in the image of that embedding.

The case of $\mathsf{PA}$ and Goodstein's theorem is fundamentally no different: we can find a (necessarily nonstandard) model $\mathfrak{M}$ of $\mathsf{PA}$ such that $\mathfrak{M}$ "thinks" that Goodstein's theorem fails. But any of the things $\mathfrak{M}$ thinks are counterexamples to Goodstein will be *nonstandard*, just as $x$ was a nonstandard element of $\mathfrak{P}$ in the example above.

---

The following old answers of mine cover related material: [on $\mathfrak{P}$ specifically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803007/how-does-induction-fail-in-computable-nonstandard-models/1803026#1803026) and [on nonstandard models in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660650/why-is-the-status-of-the-period-in-laver-tables-not-settled/3660682#3660682) (the latter is a bit technical unfortunately).

Comment: Nice answer. I think it would help the OP if you added a bit about how Goodstein's theorem can be *stated* in PA.  Also, although Tenebaum's theorem forbids a recursive nonstandard model of PA, we can still demand that the domain is $\mathbb{N}$ with "funny operations". This may make it seem more concrete.

Comment: Much thanks. This is extremely interesting. I want to know, what is the mathematical definition of "standard arithmetic"? I mean, for the set of natural numbers that humans use, "every number is either even or odd" clearly holds. Goodstein's theorem also holds. But how to mathematically define the system of arithmetic/natural numbers that humans use? We can't use any axiomatic system (like even ZFC) to define it because any axiomatic system will always be satisfied by non-standard models too. So is there a definition of it without using axiomatic systems?

Comment: I've asked the above in a separate question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4654746/what-is-the-mathematical-definition-of-standard-arithmetic-standard-natural-num

Comment: In the model of $Q$ described above, with integer polynomials, what is the successor of a polynomial?

Comment: @Weier $P(x)+1$ is the successor of $P(x)$, for any polynomial $P$ (remember that the coefficients have to be integers).